# Round off values in a datatable column to nearest 50

Tags: r

I know of round() in R, which is able to round off values by passing the number of digits to limit the value to. However, I wish to round up exact values(e.g. 1832-->1850, 1379-->1400) I get to the nearest 50, as shown in the Premium column below.

[image]

Is there a function to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to just use:

```
library(plyr)
round_any(x, 50)

round(1832, 50)
[1] 1850
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
x <- c(102, 100, 405, 1187)
round(x/50)* 50

[1]  100  100  400 1200
```